# How to get Microsoft Office 2013 to associate DBF files with excel?

Tags: file-association, microsoft-office-2013, dbf

I just installed the trial for Office 2013. I want to associate dbf files with it so I can just double click them. This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797428.aspx) says Office 2013 will open dbf files and I can open them through excel by navigating to the file from within excel.

When I try to associate dbf files with excel I go to "Open with" then "Browse" to this program "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" but it will not let me select it. I found that path by looking at the properties of the excel shortcut.

I can select "excelcnv.exe" and that will give the dbf file the excel icon but it will not open the file. It does put an option to open with "Excel" but, like I said, it doesn't work.

I also tried setting association in command prop with "assoc .dbf=Excel" and few other things but that didn't work either.

One thing that I notice is that when I go to "Open with" on an xlsx file the excel option says "Excel (desktop)".

Right now it looks like this might be a restriction due to using the trial version or maybe there is something in user files or AppData?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? By "it will not let me select it", you mean it literally is ignoring you when you try to select excel.exe, or do you get an error when you select it and press OK?

Comment: Win7 Professional. And by "not let me select" I mean that I can navigate to the application, select it to go back to the programs list, but it does not appear in the programs list after doing that.